# TypeError undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

Hi I am trying to call a function which returns me a String and once I get that string I want to perform some action. but I get an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating'(0, _cryptoUtil.encryptString) (token).then`

```
this.savePerishableTokenInSharedPrefs(res.perishableToken);

  savePerishableTokenInSharedPrefs = ( token ) => {
    const returned = encryptString(token).then((encryptedToken) => {
      //save the token
    })
    .catch(err => {
      consoleLog('error -' + err);
    });
  }
```

cryptoUtils.js

```
export function encryptString (encryptMe) {
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
    // Encrypt
    var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptMe, globals.ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    consoleLog('encryptString - ' + encryptedText + ' pin - ' + encryptMe );
    return encryptedText;
}
```

Am I missing anything basic here?.

Thanks
R

Comment: "encryptStrin**t**" is in the error message but not here. Smells like a typo.

Comment: Does `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` return a promise?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are expecting `encryptString` to return a promise but is actually returning a string.

Try this:

```
export function encryptString (encryptMe) {
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
    // Encrypt
    var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptMe, globals.ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    consoleLog('encryptString - ' + encryptedText + ' pin - ' + encryptMe );

    return Promise.resolve(encryptedText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the `encryptString` function should be asynchronous. According to [crypto-js on github](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#plain-text-encryption) you can use `toString()` on the return value and work with the result like

```
  savePerishableTokenInSharedPrefs = ( token ) => {
    try {
       const encryptedToken = encryptString(token);
       //save the token
    } catch(e => {
      consoleLog('error -' + e);
    };
  }
```